Does same site cookie/bearer token make same origin policy obsolete?
Same origin policy exists to prevent other pages steal the cookie or other sensitive information to attack the victim website. But now, we have same site cookies and local storage to for auth tokens that works on per site/origin basis, are there any remaining use cases for origin policy?
